# Why php json_encode encodes two dimensional array but outputs pure array

Tags: php, json

```
$my_array = array(
        0 => array(
                1,
                2,
                3,
            ),
        1 => array(
                1,
                2,
                3,
            ),
        2 => array(
                1,
                2,
                3,
            ),
    );
echo json_encode($my_array);
```

Result is this:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

I thought the output should be a string of json,but here outputs a pure array,why?In other words,the result should be quoted,but why this is not.

Comment: That is a string of JSON. What were you expecting, specifically?

Comment: it may look like a shorthand array version, but yes, its still also json

Comment: when I encode one dimensional array,it is like this { "if": "foo" },but this is enclosed with square brackets,also not quoted,is this json?

Comment: @user7031 [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) sees an array with string keys as an object, and [JSON syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp) surrounds objects with curly `{}` braces. The array in your question has only numeric keys, so it remains a JSON array with square `[]` brackets, and the keys remain unquoted. Look at meda's answer if you want to always encode as objects.

Comment: @wavemode when I quote the index,that became string keys,but json_encode still treated it as pure array,only 'JSON_FORCE_OBJECT' param can make the change?

Comment: @user7031 In PHP, a string containing a number such as `"5"` is the same as a number in most cases. You'll see a difference if you use non-numbers like `"dog"`.

Comment: thanks,i see the differences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
echo json_encode($my_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

**Program Output**

```
{"0":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3},"1":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3},"2":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}}
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/199168)**

Comment: that works,thanks,but what type of result I am having out there in the question?Is that a json too?

Comment: yes this is valid json as an array of array , this happens because you passed plain arrays (all integer) . try switching to words and you will notice the differnce

Comment: @user7031 did I answer your question or should I expand?